# Selenium Python Conditional Assertion

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

So I'm testing with 3 test cases:

1. Invalid email, correct password
2. Correct email, wrong password
3. Invalid email, wrong password

This is the conditional logic that I want:

1. If only an invalid email, a warning popup "Valid E-Mail is required"
2. If only the wrong password, a warning popup "Your passwords should match each other. Please recheck."
3. If an invalid email and a wrong password, a warning popup "Valid E-Mail is required" and "Your passwords should match each other. Please recheck."

What I've done so far on the script:

```
if not (re.fullmatch(regex, str(d_email))):
    assert setup.find_element("xpath", "//ul[@class='tutor-required-fields']").text == "Valid E-Mail is required"
elif d_cpassword != d_password:
    assert setup.find_element("xpath", "//ul[@class='tutor-required-fields']").text == "Your passwords should match each other. Please recheck."
elif not (re.fullmatch(regex, str(d_email))) and d_cpassword != d_password:
    assert setup.find_element("xpath", "//ul[@class='tutor-required-fields']//li[1]").text == "Valid E-Mail is required" and setup.find_element("xpath", "//ul[@class='tutor-required-fields']//li[2]").text == "Your passwords should match each other. Please recheck."
```

But I always got an error every time the program runs the third test case (invalid email & wrong password) because they read based on the first condition. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your third criteria will never be reached.  Move the third IF statement to be the first statement in your code.

Comment: I've also tried this, but then this warning "Your passwords should match each other. Please recheck." is detected when running the first test case causing it to be an error

Comment: Have you viewed the output from d_cpassword and d_password?  If so, are they the same?  Can you post the output here (using test passwords, not the actual passwords to a system)?